# How to query multiple Azure API Management API names with Application Insights query

Tags: azure, logging, azure-api-management, appinsights

Hello i was working on getting requests through the Azure API Management , however i am getting all the api exsiting. i wanted to filter just the apis i needed

here is what i did :

```
requests
|summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp,15m),toString(customDimensions.["API Name"])
where (toString(customDimensions.["API Name"]) == "api1" && "api2"
|render timechart
```

when i test it tells me  **status : something is broken** , how can i filter just the api that i need from all

Comment: did you try something like toString(customDimensions.["API Name"]) in ("api1", "api2") ?

Comment: maybe please correct question to "How to query multiple Azure API Management API names with Application Insights query" so that it is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the query to

```
requests
| extend apiName = tostring(customDimensions.["API Name"])
| summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp,15m),apiName
| where apiName in ("api1", "api2")
| render timechart
```

Comment: I found the language called kusto : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/  and yeah it worked for me , thanks

Answer (score 0):

To dive deeper into the requests, you application insights. You can link ApplicationInsights to APIM instance for monitoring.

Create `Application Insights` in Azure and copy the generated `Instrumentation key`.

Browse to APIM Resource, scroll to `Monitoring` section to select `Application Insights`. Use the above copied `Instrumentation key`.

Monitoring is not On by default for all incoming and outgoing. To enable it, in APIM scroll to API section to select `APIs`. On the top select Settings and enable Application Insights.
[image]

Now it is all set to monitor your APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution in the azure documentation .
the language is called **kusto**
here is the link to the documentation: [Azure Kusto Query language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query)

```
requests
| extend apiName = tostring(customDimensions.["API Name"])
| summarize totalCount=sum(itemCount) by bin(timestamp,15m),apiName
| where apiName in ("api1", "api2")
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

When configuring the Application Insights Diagnostics Logs, don't forget to set the number of payload bytes to an adequate value. This will give you more information from the requests and responses you are monitoring.

[image]